# How to avoid Velocity codes causing whitespaces?

Tags: whitespace, velocity

I'm using velocity template in dotCMS template files.

One problem I noticed is that velocity adds whitespaces in html source code.

Let's say I have the following source code.

```
#set($test = "aa")
#set($test2 = "aa")
<html>
<head>
...
```

when I execute the file and view source, I see the following. Basically, The first two lines are blank. How do I avoid it?

```
---- File Begin ---


<html>
<head>
...

---- File End ----
```

Comment: I can't reproduce it on version 1.7 under Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Velocity has never output whitespace from lines that have only a #set directive on them.  Are you sure the blank lines are coming from those #set lines?  Other Velocity directives are less consistent about handling whitespace, but #set is pretty clear.